# Fourier Series/Parseval's Theorem

Tags: convergence-divergence, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

[image]

I have pretty much completed [this question](http://i.gyazo.com/ba4cad78818cb8b9841d0039b5706b6c.png) and have found the Fourier representation to be;

$$ f(x) =\frac A2 +\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2A\frac{\cos(((2n-1)(\pi x))/2f_o)}{\pi(2n-1)}  $$

Now I don't understand what the question is asking for (b) and (c). Do I simply let Fourier series = 0 and then solve? For (b) then it would just be series converge to $-\frac{A}{2}$ = expand some of the series. And similarly for (c)?. Where would I go with that?

Comment: It seems that $f$ is a variable here, so what you got is actually $G(f)$. In b) you're asked to evaluate the series at $f=0$, you do it by evaluating $G(0)$.

Comment: Isn't G(f) that periodic function and what I got is the fourier series f(x) of it, by getting all coefficients and such?

Comment: I didn't check your computations, but it should be, but $f$ isn't a function here, it's a variable. Where you have $f$ you should write $G$ and where you have $x$ you should write $f$ yielding $$G(f) =\dfrac A2 +\sum \limits_{n=0}^\infty 2A\dfrac{\cos(((2n-1)(\pi f))/2f_o)}{\pi(2n-1)}.$$

Comment: Ah I see so for (b) it'd be just $$ G(f) =\frac A2 +\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2A/\pi (2n+1) $$ and likewise I can solve for (c). Is that answer sufficient or do I have to simplify it more? I don't see how besides evaluating a few terms.

Comment: That series isn't convergent, something doesn't smell good. You should wait for someone to answer you.

Comment: It is perverse to use "f" as the name for the input to a function. It is more deeply perverse to ask about pointwise convergence of such a Fourier series.

Comment: @paulgarrett: $f$ is used as a frequency variable all in time in signal analysis.  It is also far from perverse to ask that series which result from FS converge.

Comment: @RonGordon, ok, it is just a wildly different convention from any mathematical use I've seen. What do y'all call _functions_ then? "x"? :) But, sure, if it's an understood convention, I can't object.

Comment: @paulgarrett: presumably, in this case, the coefficients $G_k$ are samples in time.  For FTs, the "functions" are functions of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see...the period of this even wave is $4 f_0$, so write

$$G(f) = G_0 + 2 \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} G_k \cos{\frac{2 \pi k f}{4 f_0}} $$

$$G_k = \frac{A}{4 f_0} \int_{-f_0}^{f_0} df \, \cos{\frac{2 \pi k f}{4 f_0}} = A \frac{\displaystyle \sin{\frac{\pi k}{2}}}{\pi k}$$

So

$$G(f) = \frac{A}{2} + 2 A \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\displaystyle \sin{\frac{\pi k}{2}}}{\pi k} \cos{\frac{\pi k f}{2 f_0}} $$

A quick plot in Mathematica verified this form for $G$.

$$\begin{align}G(0) &= \frac{A}{2} + \frac{2 A}{\pi} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\displaystyle \sin{\frac{\pi k}{2}}}{k}\\ &= \frac{A}{2}+\frac{2 A}{\pi} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{2 k+1}\\ &= \frac{A}{2}+\frac{2 A}{\pi} \frac{\pi}{4}\\ &= A \end{align}$$

For $f=f_0$ you may show that the series is instead

$$G(f_0) = \frac{A}{2} + \frac{A}{\pi} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin{\pi k}}{k} = \frac{A}{2}$$

You tell me: reasonable or unreasonable?